# Access file from shared network folder

Tags: .net, nfs

I have created a nfs shared folder and from a .net web application I am returning a file from that shared folder. But I am not able to return it. Whereas when I create a windows folder in `C:\` I am able to return file to the  application.

Code as follows:

```
 public FilePathResult GetSSLRawFile(SearchPage searchpage)
        {
           string sourceFile="";
           List<_LocationDetails> Locationlist = PopulateLocationList();
           DateTime dt = searchpage.strSslDate;
           string date = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
           string strLocName = searchpage.strSSLLocName;
           string strLocID = null;
           for (int k = 0; k < Locationlist.Count; k++)
           {
               //if location id present in table T090Locations then display its ID other wise display not available
               if (Locationlist[k].strLocName == strLocName)
               {
                   strLocID = Locationlist[k].strLocID;
                   break;
               }
           }
           //if location ID is not available then display message  "File Not Found"
           if (null == strLocID) 
            {
                string strAttpath = "c:\\MI_GUI_Att\\Readme.txt";
                string ErrMsg = "File Not Found ";
                //If Error Message present than write the content to a file and return it.
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(strAttpath);
                file.WriteLine(ErrMsg);
                file.Close();
                return File(strAttpath, " ", "Readme.txt");
            }
            try     
            {
                sourceFile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSLRAWFILEPATH"].ToString(); //getting this path from web.config file
            }
            catch (Exception e) //return and display proper message in gui
            {
                ViewBag.DBError = true;
                ViewBag.ErrMsg = "Recheck 'SSLRAWFILEPATH' parameter in Web.config";
                string strAttpath = "c:\\MI_GUI_Att\\Readme.txt";                
                //If Error Message present than write the content to a file and return it.
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(strAttpath);
                file.WriteLine(ViewBag.ErrMsg);
                file.Close();  
                return File(strAttpath, " ", "Readme.txt");

            }

            string destFile = sourceFile + "\\" + strLocID + "\\" + date + "\\" + searchpage.strSslFileName;
            if (false == System.IO.File.Exists(destFile))
            {
                string strAttpath = "c:\\MI_GUI_Att\\Readme.txt";
                string ErrMsg = "File Not Found on path " + destFile;
                //If Error Message present than write the content to a file and return it.
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(strAttpath);
                file.WriteLine(ErrMsg);
                file.Close();
                return File(strAttpath, " ", "Readme.txt");

            }
            return File(destFile, " ", searchpage.strSslFileName); //Returning file name
       }
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: maybe use \\server\folder?

Comment: here the destFile is a shared folder path which i am unable to access

Comment: i need to what path is exactly used if is shared folder (e.g.) my shared folder is like share(\\192.168.0.115\home) D:\